# Java stream to find occurrences in a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write this code using Java streams which does the following -

> Take a List of KeyValuePairs and a ListOfValues, and populates a Map of `<Value, boolean>` where Value comes from ListOfValues and boolean is set to true or false based on whether value was present in ListOfKeyValuePairs.

I am starting something like:

```
keyValuePairs.stream().map(KeyValuePair::getValue) ...
```

But not able to complete it :(

Example:

```
List<KeyValuePairs> has {(1, A1), (2,A2), (3,A3)}
ListofValues has {A1,A3}
```

End result: Map with values : A1, true and A3, true

Comment: If I understand the description correctly, then the resulting map should have the same size as `ListOfValues`. It says _true or false_. Your result map has only the true entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<KeyValuePairs>` can be transformed into a `Set<Value>` to speed up further lookups:

```
var set = pairs.stream()
               .map(KeyValuePair::getValue)
               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then, if the resulting map shouldn't contain elements that haven't been found in `pairs`, filter them out by `set::contains`:

```
var map = list.stream()
              .filter(set::contains)
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> true));
```

If the resulting map should contain every element from `list`, whether or not they have been found:

```
var map = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), set::contains));
```